# Nasm code running on windows but not on linux

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, nasm, ld

I try to assemble and link my teacher's NASM code, but it does not work on my linux (Ubuntu 16.03) while it's working on her pc (Windows)

```
segment .data
a dw 10
segment .bss
segment .text
global _main:
extern _printf
_main:
_b100: mov eax, 10
_b150: mov eax, a
_b200: mov ebx, eax
fin:
ret
```

Those are the instructions i follow to assemble the code

```
nasm -g -f elf32 test.asm;ld -m elf_i386 -s -o demo *.o
```

ld returns an error

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000008048080
```

Regardless the effect of errors the executable is generated every time I run the commands but when I want to execute breakpoints on the program with gdb I can't.

Comment: Best guess you aren't linking this to an executable that uses the _C_ runtime code as an entry point. You get a warning that suggests that with the missing `_start` entry point.

Comment: the entry point is `_main:` which ends with `ret`, so this looks like it is supposed to be linked against standard C library. You would have either to add several options to the `ld` command to make this link as common C app, or use gcc for linking, which will add those by default (may need also to change `_main` to `main`, if the linker fails). `gdb` should work even with this, what is your problem? Just use `file ..`, `b *0` (to have error state upon execution), `run`, `d 1` (to delete the invalid breakpoint), and you should be in (`layout asm`, `layout reg` to see instruction, `stepi`)

Comment: @Ped7g that's a nice trick! Didn't know about it.

Comment: To get some debug info, use `nasm -F dwarf ...` so you get source code and line numbers for breakpoints.

Comment: @Jester me neither, but I did search stackoverflow 1-2days back, as somebody was claiming he's unable to debug fasm binary... it just made me to hold tighter my favourite `edb`, had to use `help <something>` to do pretty much anything in `gdb`. I can see it's usable on daily basis, but if you hit assembly debugging need once in a while, it's impossible. Would take ~30min every time just to recall all the controls and commands, while with decent text UI a la Borland you don't need to remember anything.

Comment: @Ped7g 
I wonder How can i link the code against c library with gcc ?
gdb did not work for me it returns: 
`Reading symbols from demo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.`

Comment: `nasm -g -Fdwarf -f elf32 test.asm; gcc -m32 -o demo test.o`  rename `_main` to `main` (Your teacher is using Windows and the convention on that platform with PE is to have an additional underscore on external labels)

Comment: about `gdb`: that's just warning. It works, as I noted above, you need to place breakpoint at fixed address, as you don't have debug info... or as my hack-ish suggestion, place breakpoint at invalid address (`*0`) and `run`, it will stop on invalid breakpoint, so you will be at first instruction any way.

Comment: @MichaelPetch 
it still does not work
`nasm: fatal: unrecognized debug format dwarf for output format bin
type nasm -h for help`

Comment: Did you use the exact command I showed. Seems as if from the error you didn't use `-f elf32` (error suggests it was absent on the command line you used to invoke nasm)

Comment: @MichaelPetch the format must be ahead of -F .. (just tried it myself, had to patch it a bit, in the end it works, but if you are new to these things, you will be clueless) I will answer

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly hit enter ..
nasm has generated the error i wrote in the previous comment (edited)
and ls generated a lot of errors 
it fail to find `crt1.o` `crti.o` and `cannot find -lc` `skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
` and so on

Comment: You need to do `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib` You are missing the i386 _C_ runtime and i386 libgcc etc. That command should install them.

Comment: Although no version of NASM I have on hand has the issue of order, apparently for some you have to place `-Fdwarf` after `-f elf32` so `nasm -g -f elf32 -Fdwarf test.asm; gcc -m32 -o demo test.o` , rename `_main` to `main` (if you ever use `printf` you'll need to drop the `_` as well. And this should all work after you install multilib gcc with on Ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib`

Comment: @MichaelPetch BTW, my NASM is "NASM version 2.11.08" (and requires format ahead of `-F`, by default it goes for `bin`, and `dwarf` doesn't work for that).

Comment: I seem to have NASM version 2.12.01 on my systems here which may explain it. As I said in my followup it seems to depend on environment. I'm using the latest Debian in my case on systems here. On a side note -
 I generally stay away from 2.11.08 because of the bugs it has with macho format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the code needs some patching for linux:

```
-global _main:
+global main

-_main:
+main:
```

Remove the underscore from `main` symbol. Also in the `global` directive don't add the colon, that's needed when you specify new label.

The removal of underscore will apply also to other external symbols, like `printf` or when you will publish function from your asm to the C with `global`.

Compiling:

```
nasm -g -felf32 -Fdwarf test.asm; gcc -m32 -o demo test.o
```

And you need to have `nasm`, `gcc` and 32 bit libraries installed, not sure what is the minimal set of packages, but going by `sudo apt-get install nasm gcc gcc-multilib` may be enough even on clean install of *buntu.

Comment: Since _GCC_ already was installed (given that it ran) all that would be necessary is `gcc-multilib` (all the variants of gcc require binutils and since he's just using the command line build-essentials isn't necessary. Seem to recall gcc-mulitlib has  a dependency on gcc so don't think it needs to be explicit)

Comment: The gcc-mulitlib dependency list confirms the dependency on gcc: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/gcc-multilib/4:5.2.1-3ubuntu1 so on a clean install the required dependency of gcc will be installed first (and the others) when gcc-multilib installed

Comment: Thank you so much @Ped7g and @Michael Petch. It worked after installing `gcc-multilib` and removing the underscore from main.
I still got one problem: when running `gdb`  and executing `break b100` it does not make a breakpoint but it returns `Function "b100" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load?`

Comment: @M.Iduoad Are you using _b100 or b100? in your code you have an underscore on them, and if you haven't removed them then you'll need to use the underscore in gdb as well.

Comment: I was using b100 instead of _b100. It works now ! thank you so much !